# Why is $T \Rightarrow aba$ false, but $T \stackrel{*}{\Rightarrow}$ true?

Tags: context-free-grammar

I am reading Sipser's book and encountered a question with this regular grammer:

$$
R \Rightarrow XRX~|~S \\
S \Rightarrow aTa~|~bTa \\
T \Rightarrow XTX~|~X~|~\varepsilon \\
X \Rightarrow a~|~b
$$

Apparently, the solutions in the back say that $T \Rightarrow aba$ is false. Why? Isn't this a derivation for $aba$?

$$
T \Rightarrow XTX \Rightarrow aTa \Rightarrow aXa \Rightarrow aba
$$

On the other hand, $T \Rightarrow aba$, where the arrow has an asterisk on top of the arrow (I'm not sure how to make this symbol in LateX), is true. Why is there a difference?

Comment: You can make $\stackrel{*}{\Rightarrow}$ in $\LaTeX$ using `\stackrel{*}{\Rightarrow}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Sipser, the $u \Rightarrow v$ notation means that *after a single step* you can obtain $v$ from $u$ (applying a single rule to a single variable in $u$).

On the other hand $u \Rightarrow^* v$ means that after *some number of steps* you can obtain $v$ from $u$.

So $T \not\Rightarrow aba$ since the only strings you can obtain from $T$ after a single step are $$XTX; \quad X; \quad \varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 4):

$T \stackrel{*}{\Rightarrow} aba$ means that you can derive $aba$ from $T$ after applying grammar rules one or more times (as you did in your question). On the other hand, $\Rightarrow$ (without the asterisk), means that the derivation happens in only one step.